# switch off proxy in requests library

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I've been using the `requests` library in some Python code, and I need some help navigating the murky waters of corporate proxy servers.

Consider the following code:

```
response = requests.get(url, proxies={...})
```

All good so far. The `requests` call uses the proxies passed to it.

In the next example, `requests` uses proxies defined in the environment variables `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY`:

```
response = requests.get(url)
```

(The `proxies` parameter defaults to None, which triggers it to go and look at the environment variables.)

What I want to do is something different. I want to leave the environment variables as they are, because they're necessary for other applications I use. But I want requests NOT to use a proxy. I've tried:

```
response = requests.get(url, proxies={})
```

but `requests` still goes off and gets the environment variable proxies. I can't seem to stop it doing that, without unsetting my environment variables.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [`trust_env` variable on the session](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Session.trust_env) to `False`. If not true (`True` is the default), proxy information from the environment is ignored altogether:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.trust_env = False
response = session.get(url)
```

This does also disable [`.netrc` authentication](https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/html_node/The-_002enetrc-file.html) support. If you need that still, then you have two more options that I can see:

- add a `NO_PROXY` environment variable; set to `*` means no proxies should be used at all. You could do this by directly setting the key in the `os.environ` dictionary.
- simply delete the proxy keys from `os.environ`.

  Take into account that on OSX and Windows Python will look for proxies in the system configuration too (so the registry on Windows, and SysConf on Mac OS X).

Altering `os.environ` is safe. It is a regular dictionary, adding or deleting keys  in your program is fine, the parent shell environment won't be altered.

Comment: Why does `NO_PROXY` work? Internally, `requests` just calls `urllib.getproxies()` (I dug through the source code to check this) which just looks for environment variables of the form `<scheme>_proxy`. How can a new environment variable override this seemingly brute force search through the space of environment variables?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan: You missed the `should_bypass_proxies()` calls then.